# Как передать результат выполнения асинхронного запроса обратно в вызвавшую его активность?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-asynctask

Есть окно с элементом `spinner`, который должен заполняться значениями из базы данных MS SQL. Для связи с БД использую jtds 1.2.8 в асинхронных запросах, но никак не выходит найти способ чтобы переправить данные результата запроса в активность, которая послала асинхронный запрос. Как реализовать заполнение `spinner` после выполнения запроса?

UA.java

```
public class UA extends AppCompatActivity{

private QueryItem Item = new QueryItem();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ua);
    Item.setId(Search_Page.id_intent);
    Search_Page.id_intent = 0;
    String[] query = new String[2];
    query[1] = "get_dish_links";
    query[0] = "EXEC " + query[1] + "" + Item.getId();
    new AsyncRequest().execute(query);
    final SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    //Item.setUnit(spinner);
}

public void fill_spinner(List<Link> links){
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<Link> possible_units = new ArrayAdapter<Link>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, links);
    spinner.setAdapter(possible_units);
    spinner.setSelection(0);
    possible_units.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

AsyncRequest.java

```
public final class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {

    public final static String MSSQL_DB = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433; DatabaseName=Lazycook";
    public final static String MSSQL_LOGIN = "lazyuser";
    public final static String MSSQL_PASS = "12344321";
    public final static JSONConverter conv = new JSONConverter();
    public String action;

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String[] query) {
        JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();
        action = query[1];
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(MSSQL_DB, MSSQL_LOGIN, MSSQL_PASS);
                if (con != null) {
                    st = con.createStatement();
                    rs = st.executeQuery(query[0]);
                    if (rs != null) {
                        int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                        // Сохранение данных в JSONArray
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();
                            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                                rowObject.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), (rs.getString(i) != null) ? rs.getString(i) : "");
                            }
                            resultSet.put(rowObject);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (rs != null) rs.close();
                    if (st != null) st.close();
                    if (con != null) con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultSet;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        switch (action){
            case "get_dish_links" : {
                List<Link> links = conv.JSONtoLink(result);
                // вот здесь думал использовать вызов fill_spinner
                // нужного объекта, передав ему результат
            }


        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Создайте интерфейс

   ```
   public interface MyInterface
   {
       void doSmth(JSONArray result);
   }
   ```
2. Реализуйте его в активити

   ```
   public class UA extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface{

       @Override
       public void doSmth(JSONArray result)
       {
           System.out.println("вызван doSmth в Активити");
           //вот и ваш результат из задачи в актвити
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Передавайте его в задачу через конструктор и вызывайте его метод, передавая туда результат из `onPostExecute`:

   ```
   public final class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {

       MyInterface myInterface;

       public AsyncRequest(MyInterface myInterface){
           this.myInterface = myInterface;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
           System.out.println("вызван onPostExecute");
           myInterface.doSmth(result);
       }
   }
   ```
4. В активити запускайте так:

   ```
   new AsyncRequest(UA.this).execute(query);
   ```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогло)

Comment: Хотя тут другой вопрос возникает.. Почему-то onPostExecute начинает выполняться только после того, как закрываю UA и, соответственно, до этого ничего не обновляется (дебагом выявил, ибо ошибок/исключений не сыпет, но в `seekbar` ничего не появляется

Comment: @Vsevolod, я у вас в коде не вижу чтоб вы пытались что-то с сикБаром делать. Плюс удостоверьтесь, что в задаче вашей вы не пытаетесь ещё одну задачу асинхронную начать. В любом случае попробуйте убрать вообще всё из задачи и просто верните из неё деволтные данные. Исходя из этого пытайтесь не дефолтные достать и вернуть.

Comment: извиняюсь, дурацкая ошибка, я имел в виду `spinner`

Comment: @Vsevolod, проверьте без запуска задачи создать спиннер с данными. Если не получится - значит проблема не в задаче.