# Как вернуть значение из AsyncTask в MainActivity

Tags: android

Есть Главная активность, в которой есть переменная, которая должна хранить погоду.
Так же есть класс, в котором статичная функция возвращает текстовое значение текущей погоды (String stringWeather = Weather.getWeather(); - его расписывать не буду, так как он работает)

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private String weather;
  private final String LOCATION = "moscow";

  @Override 
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WeatherThread weatherThread = (WeatherThread) new WeatherThread(this, LOCATION).execute();
    try { weather = weatherThread.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
}
```

Так как в главном потоке нельзя делать запрос к серверу, используем AsyncTask.
Создаем его в отдельном файле, чтобы не загромождать код главной активности

```
public class WeatherThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  private String param;
  private Context context;

  public WeatherThread(Context context, String param) {
    this.context = context;
    this.param = param;
  }
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    return Weather.getWeather(); // тот самый запрос к серверу. Возвращает String.
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
  }
}
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы потом из переменной weather вывести значение на экран и, например, отправить через мессенджер кому-нибудь.

Проблема состоит в том, что при попытке обращения к переменной weather в главном потоке, генерируется исключение `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Такое ощущение, что Вы как-то неправильно используете `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Строка не может выдавать такое исключение

Comment: Метод `get` не асинхронный. Он останавливает поток до получения результата или истечения таймаута - это равносильно запросу в главном потоке.

Comment: А чем его можно заменить?

Comment: Запускайте методом `execute`, а всё, что нужно выполнить после получения результата вызывайте из `onPostExecute`

Comment: Как вариант, в методе `onPostExecute(...)` можно вызвать коллбэк активити и передать туда результат выполнения запроса. Далее в коллбэке обрабатывать результат. И еще: хранение ссылки на активити в асинстаске чревато утечкой памяти.

Comment: А можно пример коллбэка, пожалуйста?

Comment: Смотрите тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517535/17609

Comment: Спасибо, пришла идея выполнять расшаривание погоды в AsyncTask. То есть, если смотреть на ваш пример, вызывать `new AsyncRequest(UA.this).execute(query);` по нажатию на кнопочку в UI.

Comment: ЮрийСПБ, все сработало! Спасибо за идею!